# spring boot do not publish correctly font files from static dir (font-awesome)

Tags: spring-boot

I cannot manage to make spring boot publish correctly the font files.

Since I migrate to spring boot, font-awesome didn't display the icons correctly, instead I got a square.

In this case my files are local, the urls are good because I can see them loaded in network tab of the chrome console.

If I change the css loading in the header by using the maxcdn link :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-   awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

then it works. The problem is that I got other woff to load that are not in maxcdn (simple-line-icons plugin).

I put all my static files in src/main/resources/static

Here is a picture of what I get in chrome (square icons + network info) (open the image link in a new tab to see in large size)

[image]

Apparently chrome says that the font awesome woff file is transfered with mime text/plain

Here is a pic with content of font awesome fonts dir. original font size (on top) and the same dir filtered with maven (on bottom) size are slightly different

[image]

Here is my pom part were I do maven filtering :

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>dev</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/dev.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>webdev1</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>webdev1</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/webdev1.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>prod</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/prod.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

---

#### Solved

The problem was due to maven filtering resources, I've updated my pom.xml to exclude the static dir

Comment: This works for me with Spring Boot's default configuration. Have you included all of Font Awesome's files beneath src/main/resources/static? If you have then perhaps you can share a project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your response. All files are normally correctly added, I was migrating an old spring xml app witch contains font awesome. I'm going to update my initial post with my config files, I have nothing special I guess. I have another plugin using .woff files and I have the same problem. I can see that files are loaded in chrome, the mime seems ok but no icons are displayed

Comment: I have updated my initial post with more info on the problem. If you don't find something, I can make a test project to try to reproduce the error

Comment: The file size for `fontawesome-webfont.woff` looks suspicious to me. I'd expect it to be ~70KB not 125KB. Perhaps the file is corrupted, possibly due to resource filtering at build time?

Comment: I think you're right, I've upload a pic in the original post with on top the size of the original font awesome fonts files and on bottom the same dir filtered in the target dir. It looks likes some files are bigger ... I 've add some maven filtering for profiles perhaps I'm doing something wrong with it.

Comment: Ok ! it's working ! I have excluded all the static dir contains in /src/main/resources/static so maven won't filter those files. Now I didn't get a corrupted font file !!! Thanks Andy you save my day !

Comment: Thank you for the update. You should add it as an answer :)